# adding corners to my tabs background in android coding

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I was implementing a drawable file to add a background to my tabs but i want it to have corners . I've used a shape and corners tags all embedded into a selector tag but it has no  effects to my background corners . May I please get your help ? here's the code i've implemented :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/bleue_sky" android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
                android:topRightRadius="15dp"
                />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blackTransparent"/>

</selector>
```

[image: I want the background in blue to have corners]

Comment: Could you add an image (draw it in MS Paint) to show us what the expected result you want?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI , i've just edited the code  . I just want the borders of the background to be round

Comment: Something similar to : https://imgur.com/nSV4m7v ?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI exactly .. Look at my  edit , i've added a picture

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI , thanks but this code doesn't help me that much .. if i wrap them all , they all have the background at the same time but what i want is them to get the background when clicked (  i figured out it) . My only preoccupation is to get the borders rounded using a selector tag like in the code in the post

Comment: check the Mayur answer, if does not work with you let us know

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI it has finally worked !! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/main_tab_bg"
                android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_layout_background"
                app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_layout_indicator"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
                app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="true"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
                app:tabMode="auto"
                app:tabRippleColor="@null"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#FFFFFF"
                app:tabTextColor="#000000" />
```

res/drawable/main_tab_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#DDDDDD"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

res/drawable/tab_layout_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="9dp"
        android:bottom="9dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <size android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

res/drawable/tab_layout_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="9dp"
        android:bottom="9dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
            <size android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

output like this

[image]